# primefaces dropdown with enums as table filter returning Value is not vallid

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, drop-down-menu, primefaces, enums

I have two dropdowns as a table/column filter in JSF primefaces p:dataTable which are populated by ENUMS, when I select the value from the first one and then I get the validation error

```
    form:billingTable:methodDropdown: Validation Error: Value is not validform:billingTable:methodDropdown: Validation Error: Value is not valid
```

I assume that the problem is with the empty selectoin from the second drop down, but I dont find the way how to fix it.

Both enums are returned as List and not as EnumType[]

The table is presented as LazyDataModel

I am using the omnifaces GenericEnumConverter

The code:

1.) The first dropdown

```
@Named
public class PaymentMethodsForDropDown {

    private ArrayList<PaymentMethod> paymentMethods;

    @Produces
    @Named(value = "paymentMethods")
    @ViewScoped
    public ArrayList<PaymentMethod> getPaymentMethods() {
        if (paymentMethods == null) {
            paymentMethods = new ArrayList<>();
            for (PaymentMethod pm : PaymentMethod.values()) {
                paymentMethods.add(pm);
            }
        }
        return paymentMethods;
    }

}
```

The XHTML

```
<p:column id="methodColumn" headerText="Method of payment" filterBy="#{bill.method}" sortBy="#{bill.method}"  > 
                        <f:facet  name="filter">
                            <h:selectOneMenu  id="methodDropdown" onchange="PF('billingTable').filter()"  value="#{lazyBillingModel.paymentMethod}" style="width:130px;" converter="omnifaces.GenericEnumConverter" >
                                 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{paymentMethods}" var="var" itemValue="#{var}" itemLabel="#{var.name}" />   
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{bill.method.name}" />
                    </p:column>
```

2.) the second dropdown

```
@Named
public class PaymentStatusDropDown {

    private ArrayList<PaymentStatus> paymentStatuses;

    @Produces
    @Named(value = "paymentStatuses")
    @ViewScoped
    public ArrayList<PaymentStatus> getPaymentStatus() {
        if (paymentStatuses == null) {
            paymentStatuses = new ArrayList<>();
            for (PaymentStatus ps : PaymentStatus.values()) {
                paymentStatuses.add(ps);
            }
        }
        return paymentStatuses;
    }

}


 <p:column  id="statusColumn"  headerText="Status of payment" filterBy="#{bill.status}" sortBy="#{bill.status}">
                        <f:facet name="filter"> 
                            <h:selectOneMenu  id="statusDropdown" onchange="PF('billingTable').filter()" style="width:100px;"  value="#{lazyBillingModel.paymentStatus}" converter="omnifaces.GenericEnumConverter" >
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{paymentStatuses}" var="item" itemValue="#{item}"  itemLabel="#{item.name}" /> 
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{bill.status.name}" />
                    </p:column>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you should return List<> and not ArrayList<> in `PaymentMethodsForDropDown` and in `PaymentStatusDropDown`.

```
@Named
public class PaymentStatusDropDown {

      private List<PaymentStatus> paymentStatuses;

      @Produces
      @Named(value = "paymentStatuses")
      @ViewScoped
      public List<PaymentStatus> getPaymentStatus() {
          if (paymentStatuses == null) {
              paymentStatuses = new ArrayList<>();
              for (PaymentStatus ps : PaymentStatus.values()) {
                  paymentStatuses.add(ps);
              }
           }
          return paymentStatuses;
          }
}
```